a discrepancy between the arima model and plot
I ran the arima model and estimated the fitted values.  My constant value in the arima model is 153.  Since the time variable (t_centered) was centered at zero, the constant indicates a predicted value at zero.  However, the red line at zero in Time hovers about 185.  I just wonder why there are a gap between the constant of the arima model and plotted value at 0 in Time.  Both should be similar or the same.  Is my understanding correct?
Note: When I ran an ols model, I did not have said problem.
# fit ARIMA model
arima(x = data[, "dv"], order = c(4, 0, 0), xreg = data[, c("t_centered ", " t_centered2", "x1", "t_centered_x1", "t_centered2_x1", "x2", "x3",  "x4", "x5")], include.mean = T)

# estimate fitted values
data$fitted_m_all = fitted(m_all)

# plot observed and fitted values:  
gall <- ggplot(data, aes(x = t_centered, y = dv, color = x1) ) +
  geom_point(color="grey",size=2.5) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", linewidth = 1.2, se=F, 
              mapping=aes(y=fitted_m_all), formula=y~poly(x,2)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, alpha = 1, 
             linewidth = .5, linetype = "solid", color="black") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-30, 30), ylim = c(50, 250))+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")+ 
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Number")
gall



Hi: Your question is difficult to follow because there's no access to the data so the R code cannot be run. But,  still I don't see why you would expect the intercept to be plotted at time equals zero because there are a whole bunch of other coefficients in the model besides the intercept. But I'm most likely not following which is why it would be helpful to be able to run the R code.
